# "Proper way" to add a folder to the include path in XCode 4

Tags: c++, xcode, include

I know that there is a way to add a "Search Path" in XCode settings for a specific project.

[image]

(* I know about this)

But I'm interested to know the "proper" way to permanently add an include folder to XCode.

What I did was add `<Eigen>` to `/usr/include`.  My code now goes:

```
#include </usr/include/Eigen/Eigen> // works ok
```

But it really should look like

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen> // does NOT work
```

But XCode does NOT seem to consider `/usr/include` as part of the build path.  Indeed, it gets ALL its header files (including ones like `<stdio.h>`) from a path like

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include
```

Wow, what a sweet path.

I'm not sure I want to fiddle with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include`, but at the same time, I don't want to modify my XCode project settings each time I want to simply `#include <Eigen/Eigen>`.

What is the RECOMMENDED way to add a folder to XCode's INCLUDE path, so that it works **for every new project automatically?**

Comment: I would have thought that you don't want to add "custom" include directories so that they go into EVERY project - aside from the standard include directory of the tools you are using, that is.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the Get Info window (Cmd + I)
Select the Build tab
Add the directories you'd like to include under "Search Header Paths"

You'd have to do this for every project you would want to include with Eigen but I think that is the recommended way to do things.  Just keep it in one place and have all projects that use it reference that location

Comment: I'm thinking it's easier to just type `#include "/usr/include/Eigen/Eigen"` rather than have to manually configure every project.

Comment: And when the path changes on a different machine? For example /usr/local/include/eigen/Eigen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

- Add **$(PROJECT_DIR)/Your/Include/Folder** to the **User Search Paths**
- Make **Always Search User Paths** = **Yes**